# How to use pseudo-class :target within an image map

Tags: css, css-selectors, imagemap

I have a `<div>` classed as `class="tooltip"` which is normally hidden with `display:none`.

I would like the `<div>` to show with `display:block` when an area of my image-map is clicked. I am planning on using the `:target` pseudo-class.

Here is the simplified version of my code :

```
<img id="slot" class="single" src="slot.png" usemap="#slot"/>

<map name="slot">
    <area
         shape="poly"
         coords="30,0,61,15,31,31,0,16"
         alt="Slot"
         href="#trigger-happy">
</map>

<div class="fixed-container">
    <div class="tooltip">
            Slot
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the trick is that the `href` is hidden away within the `<area>` tag. From what I understand, it is currently impossible to select a parent with pure CSS.

Would you have any suggestions on how to perform this task ? I'm not familiar with JavaScript, so a pure CSS answer would be ideal. I know I'll have to get down to JS eventually however, so a JS fix would also be acceptable if there is no other way.

It should be noted that I can already achieve similar results with the `:hover` pseudo-class, by applying it to the `map` tag. When using `map:hover`, the browser reacts perfectly. However, for actual clicking rather than hovering, I'm not sure I can just use `<a>` with `<map>`, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are targeting `#trigger-happy` via `href`, therefore you would add `id="trigger-happy"` to the element `.tooltip`.

Here is a [**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/BR8yF/).

**Updated HTML:**

```
<div class="fixed-container">
    <div id="trigger-happy" class="tooltip">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Use the [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3atarget) pseudo class to style the targeted element, `#trigger-happy`.

The base CSS would look like this:

```
#trigger-happy {
    display:none;
}

#trigger-happy:target {
    display:block;
}
```

The downside to the `:target` approach is that once something is clicked, it is clicked. There isn't any toggling available with this option. I imagine you could use the checkbox hack if you wanted it to be toggleable, otherwise JS would be needed.

Comment: Actually, you can just have a "close" button which targets "#", and this should cancel the original target effect.